# Ansible: How to get the interface name of the host machine where ansible connect from?

Tags: ansible

I would like to determine the interface ipv6 address of the host, where ansible connects from and use it as variable in my playbook. I know how to get the ipv6 address from the facts:

```
{{ ansible_facts['ens192']['ipv6'][0]['address'] }}
```

My only problem is that the interface might be something else but ens192, because I have hosts with multiple interfaces. I always need that interface's address where ansible connect to host, which might be ensX

If you could provide me a solution for IPv4, it is good enough for me. :) Please note that default_ipv4_address does not work for me, because the default interface is not always where the ansible connection is coming.

**UPDATE:**

I think it will be good if I could get the IPv6 address where ansible connects to and get it's variable somehow. So if ansible connects to host1.something.local and it has an IPv6 address: 2001:1:2:3::4 get that IPv6 address as variable and use it in playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got a solution that works, but for what it's worth you could also just query your routing tables for that information.  The `ip route get` command will show you both the interface name and source address used to connect to another host.  For example:

```
$ ip route get 2607:f8b0:4006:800::200e
2607:f8b0:4006:800::200e from :: via 2001:470:1f06:46f::1 dev he-ipv6 proto static src 2001:470:1f06:46f::2 metric 675 pref medium
```

From the above output, we see that a connection to `2607:f8b0:4006:800::200e` will use interface `he-ipv6` and source address `2001:470:1f06:46f::2`.

You could use this in a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: targethost
  tasks:
    - name: get local address
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: >-
        ip route get {{ hostvars['targethost'].ansible_default_ipv6.address }}
      register: route

    - set_fact:
        local_address: "{{ dict(route_parts|zip(route_parts[1:])).src }}"
        local_interface: "{{ dict(route_parts|zip(route_parts[1:])).dev }}"
      vars:
        route_parts: "{{ route.stdout.splitlines()[0].split()[1:] }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "local address: {{ local_address }}"
          - "local interface: {{ local_interface }}"
```

This should work with both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.

Comment: A bit complicated, but I accept the solution because it is the exact answer for my question. Could be usefull later.

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to return the interface of the local side and not the side on the host running ansible

Comment: @jdi then there is something wrong with your playbook: if this play is targeting a remote host, it is running the `ip route get` command *on the remote host*; it doesn't know anything about the local host network environment.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I think I found it:

```
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2] }}
```

This will get the address where ansible connects to. If IPv6 is preferred, then it will be an IPv6 address. Otherwise it will be an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

1.This is the most simple way to get the default ip address which the default route points to

```
"{{ ansible_default_ipv6.address }}"
```

As for variable `ansible_default_ipv6`, you can get more infomation.

such as interface name, gateway, mac address and so on.

2.another workaround method

You can get all ipv6 address of the host from this variable

```
"{{ ansible_all_ipv6_addresses }}"
```

And according to the ip address,
you can distinguish the ip address which is in same 'network segment' of ansible host

Tips: replace `ipv6` with `ipv4`, also works fine

Comment: This will not work. I did a try at the frist time, but ansible_default_ipvx_address will bring me up that netowrk's address, where the default route is set to. This isn't always the address where ansible connects to. (think the situation where is a local network and ansible connects to there)